# Add time stamp for hover in Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, leaflet, qualtrics

I'm using Leaflet to insert a map into Qualtrics. For one of my markers, I have it set up so that (1) a popup appears with a mouse hover and (2) clicking on the popup continues on to the next page in the experiment:

```
marker1.on('mouseover', function (e) {
      this.openPopup();
      this.getPopup()._contentNode.onclick = function () {
      document.querySelector("#NextButton").click();
      Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("home", "one");
     };
    });
```

Is it also possible to use embedded data to also record when the mouse hover occurs with a time stamp? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to get a `new Date()`. When no parameters are provided, the newly-created Date object represents the current date and time as of the time of instantiation. Then you can get the parameters you wish using the `getDay()`, `getMonth()`, `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`, etc... return your timestamp and then you can call on the function within your event listener `mouseover`.

Not sure how you wish to save it further however...

```js
const getTimeStamp = () => {
  let d = new Date();
  let hours = d.getHours();
  let meridian;
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    meridian = 'PM';
  }else{
    meridian = 'AM';
  }
  let time = `${hours}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()} ${meridian}`;
  let day = d.getDate();
  let month = d.getMonth() + 1; // Since getMonth() returns month from 0-11 not 1-12
  let year = d.getFullYear();
  let timeStamp = `${month}/${day}/${year} - ${time}`;
  return timeStamp;
}

let marker1 = document.getElementById('marker1')

marker1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  console.log(getTimeStamp())
  //  this.openPopup();
  //  this.getPopup()._contentNode.onclick = function() {
  //    document.querySelector("#NextButton").click();
  //    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("home", "one");
  //  };
});
```

```html
<buttton id="marker1">Marker</div>
```